# File upload in form submit using Protractor js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

Code :

```
 <form name="addImageForm" id="addImageForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Select Image</label>
    <div class="input-group">
    <input id="fileName" class="form-control" placeholder="Select a image"/>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
    <div class="btn btn-info btn-file">
    Browse <input id="image" name="image" type="file" onchange="getFileName()" accept="image/*" />
    <input type="hidden" id="companyId" name="companyId" value="{{loggeduserinfo.companyId}}" />
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Save</button>
    <button id="cancel" ng-click="navigate('/images')" type="button" class="btn pull-left buttonMargin">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Protractor JS file :

```
 var fileName = "golden_ubuntu.jpg";
    var fileToUpload = '../Pictures/' + fileName;
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
    var fileElem = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));
    browser.executeScript('arguments[0].style = {};', fileElem.getWebElement());
    fileElem.sendKeys(absolutePath);
    browser.sleep(1000);
    element(by.buttonText('Save')).click();
```

Issue :
The Save button click doesn't result in form submission

Comment: Are there any other buttons having `Save` text? Are you sure the `absolutePath` contains the path to an existing file? Thanks.

Comment: Yes alecxe, I'm sure the absolutePath contains existing path. About Save button, there are no other buttons apart from browse and save button